# Activating NLA on Windows Server 2003 RDP Client

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, network-level-auth

I am trying to connect to a new Windows Server 2008 R2 machine via RDP from a Server 2003 machine.  I have (and would like to keep) enabled the requirement for NLA (Network Level Authentication) which is provided in RDP client 6.1.  Unfortunately, RDP 6.1 doesn't seem to be available for Server 2003.  Is there a way to do so without totally disabling NLA on the 2008 box?

Comment: I have searched for this in the past.  AFAIK the answer to this is no, NLA is not supported from Windows 2003 and there is nothing you can do to change that.

Comment: If that is not available, is there a way to "selectively" disable NLA for particular clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, NLA is not supported on Server 2k3 clients.

If you want, you can disable NLA by running tsconfig.msc on your 2008 R2 server, and deselecting the "Allow connection only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication" option under the RDP service.

Comment: Would rather not have to do that globally to only support one client.

Comment: You can set up another RDP listener on a second interface, and firewall that interface to only accept connections from a certain client. It's not an elegant workaround, but it would get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Hyppy, its too bad Windows has dropped the ball on this.